# Multiple pip locations and versions, and pip not updating - Ubuntu on WSL

Tags: python, pip

## Why are there so many versions and locations of pip?

When I run `pip install -U pip` it says it's updating to a newer version, then when I run `pip --version` it's the un-updated version. I am on WSL.

[image: so many pips...]

Comment: No screenshots of text (or code)! Instead copy-paste the text into your question.

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @sinoroc I've now installed pyenv and cannot get this original text back... but I tried. Also found that `/usr/bin/pip[3]` and `/bin/pip[3]` point to `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip` while `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/pip[3]` points to `/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip`... so looks like I only have 2 versions installed actually.

Comment: If I were you I would uninstall all _pip_ installations, and only use the _pip_ that comes in virtual environments, this is how I do it. -- Probably you need to figure out how to cleanly uninstall the local installations at `/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/pip*`, and then uninstall the global installations, probably with something like `sudo apt autoremove python-pip`, not sure exactly. -- I do not know how `pyenv` is supposed to help in your case.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to the command you are running to open `Python`, then upgrade `pip` through it's module.

EDIT: for clarification
When Running the script for example in vscode or wsl your command will be the direct path to your specific python install. So whatever way you are starting the python script just adjust it to use  pip upgrade

e.g.

/bin/Python3.10/python pythonScript.py

would be

/bin/Python3.10/python -m pip install --upgrade pip

Otherwise, you will need to update your Environmental Variables in WSL to use a certain version of python with 'python' and a certain pip with 'pip3'

EDIT2: Also VENV may help your situation :)

Comment: How does this solve the problem asked in the question?

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 0):

I think you have multiple Python version installed on the same machine, if this is the case try using `pipx.x install --upgrade pip` where `x.x` is the Python version you want to use.

As far as I know each Python installation has its own pip, so you need to select a specific version.

Then there is the system interpreter, which is the *default* Python version run by your terminal and this is the version used when you simply use `pip` without any `x.x` version selection.

See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2812520/dealing-with-multiple-python-versions-and-pip) solves your issue.